# How could 'F' be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '(...a: Parameters<F>) => number'?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

If the return value derives its rest parameter type from `F`, how could `F` be instantiated with a different subtype?

```js
function wrap<F extends (...a: Parameters<F>) => number>(f: F): F {
  return (...a: Parameters<F>) => f(...a)
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
}
```

```
Type '(...a: Parameters<F>) => number' is not assignable to type 'F'.
  '(...a: Parameters<F>) => number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'F', but 'F' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '(...a: Parameters<F>) => number'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Functions in JavaScript are objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) and are therefore allowed to have properties like other objects.  And just like `T extends {a: string}`,  is allowed to have more properties than just `a`, `F extends (...a: any) => any` is allowed to have more properties than just those found on `Function.prototype`:

```
function magicFunction(x: string, y: number) {
    return x.length + y;
}
magicFunction.magic = "abracadabra!!";
```

Or equivalently

```
const magicFunction = Object.assign(
  (x: string, y: number) => x.length + y, 
  { magic: "abracadabra!!" }
);
```

So the type of `magicFunction` is

```
// const magicFunction: ((x: string, y: number) => number) & { magic: string; }
```

which has a `magic` property of type `string`.

---

The call signature of `wrap()` claims to return the same exact type as its argument:

```
const wrappedMagicFunction = wrap(magicFunction);
// const wrappedMagicFunction: typeof magicFunction
```

But the implementation only returns a function of type `((x: string, y: number) => number)`:

```
console.log(wrappedMagicFunction("abcde", 8)) // 13, okay
```

And not necessarily a function of the same type as the input; in particular, it does not have the requisite `magic` property:

```
console.log(wrappedMagicFunction.magic.toUpperCase()); // compiles okay, but
//  RUNTIME ERROR! wrappedMagicFunction.magic is undefined
```

Since the implementation cannot be verified to satisfy the call signature, the compiler complains.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOAeAYogUwA8oCwATAZ0QAoA6B9ALkQAV0MBbA01SvAHwBKRAF4BiMCE4AjAqgE1gLXEJWIA3gChEuxKh4hUSeoxbsuPef1zCxE4KbrohOvQHp3APx++--gMCg3y0AXy0I9wAqUEhYBEROdABzGAhccGh4MBoiFkooVBgwZIAaRABPFilZeRFtPX1DY0QiOgAbMmSoAAtEAGpKgG4wrSTU9Mz4sDpxtLFEACJ0GQwIdHIVjABCbcWRqPctCAQCxJS0jLjshYB5GQArAmhnSkoYZJzc-MLissrqtI5KgROJWh0ur0BpVyhpzhMWMtVuh1ptkbtFohQkIRlpPIgTmAznNJtcECwaN9EAUiiVylVJEC6vZGbUQYgAGSaXQkn605JDLERQlnNBYTAEcgAWQupKyCVEKAwmBoJKu8rAOLxUQJpygSvFkplE3V0wpVJpf3pgLZoIkNWBIi5cN51N+JUFoUQh2OpzgnQ6cGSNDFmAl0tlpuyNCREHIBEW5QAHEIRPiAIwAZnKcAA1ugKr6if6CIHg6Hw8bLlNsrNZXQoHAAKph+QAYXQlAINFTgvxACUmwA5AAqAEkpQBRRCT-v92797YG1sRk01hB1iaIGDUcDx4DFSVAA)